# Sequencing RXJS chaining / processing of NGRX observables in an HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am having trouble attaching a JWT access token to the header of an HTTP request within a class which derives from the HttpInterceptor (Angular 8) base class.

I have narrowed the issue down to the sequence in which the operations are performed within the Http Interceptor. It appears the request is sent to the caller before the token is returned back from the NGRX store (async).

I am unclear how to ensure that the request is only returned back once the token has been received back from the NGRX store.

```
export class ServerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor, OnDestroy {

    private state$: Observable<any>;
    private unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;

    constructor(
        private store: Store<AuthenticationState>
    ) {
        this.unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
        this.state$ = this.store.select(getAccessToken);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsubscribeAll.next();
        this.unsubscribeAll.complete();
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const output = next.handle(request).pipe(
            takeUntil(this.unsubscribeAll),
            withLatestFrom(
                this.store.select(selectAuthenticationState), (_action, state) => {
                    console.log(state.accessToken);
                    if (state.accessToken) {
                        request = request.clone({
                            setHeaders: {
                              Authorization: `Bearer ${state.accessToken}`
                            }
                          });
                    }
                    console.log('1');
                    return request;
                }
            ),
            switchMap((req) => {
                console.log('2');
                return next.handle(req);
            }),            
        );
        console.log('3');
        return output;
    }
}
```

The output of the console processes the interceptor in the sequence 3, 1 and 2. It should be processed 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using `select` operator with your selector `getAccessToken`, and "chain" observables.
No need to subscribe if you use `first()` or `take(1)` operators. Observable will automatically complete after one value.

Your code for `HttpInterceptor` could looks like below:

```
export class ServerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AuthenticationState>
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(getAccessToken),
      first(),
      mergeMap(accessToken => {

        const authReq = !!accessToken ? request.clone({
          headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
        }) : request;

        return next.handle(authReq);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Some resources on the subject :

- [Using NgRx Store Auth Token with Angular HttpInterceptor](https://antonyderham.me/post/angular-ngrx-auth-interceptor/) by Antony Derham
- [Add JWT Token to Angular HTTP Requests Using NGRX](http://www.webappsolution.com/blog/2018/12/18/add-jwt-token-to-angular-http-requests-using-ngrx) by WASi

Comment: That works like a charm. You are a super star. Thank you!